# Fillna only if the condition of another column is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, fillna

I have a dataframe **test** that looks like this:

```
| sales |transactions|
|-------|------------|
|0.0    |NaN         |
|0.0    |NaN         |
|3802.29|NaN         |
|4520.35|8359        |
```

I'm looking for a way to fill the NaN values with 0 of only the rows that have 0 in the 'sales' column, without changing the other rows. I tried this:

```
test['transactions'] = test.apply(
        lambda row: 0 if row['sales'] == 0 else None,
        axis=1)
```

It works for those rows but the problem is that fills with NaN all the other rows

Output:

```
| sales |transactions|
|-------|------------|
|0.0    |0.0         |
|0.0    |0.0         |
|3802.29|NaN         |
|4520.35|NaN         |
```

Expected result:

```
| sales |transactions|
|-------|------------|
|0.0    |0.0         |
|0.0    |0.0         |
|3802.29|NaN         |
|4520.35|8359        |
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `mask`

Specifically, use the `other` argument in `mask`

```
df.assign(
    transactions=df.transactions.mask(df.sales == 0, other=0)
)

     sales  transactions
0     0.00           0.0
1     0.00           0.0
2  3802.29           NaN
3  4520.35        8359.0
```

---

In the event you have a transaction that isn't null where sales are zero and don't want to replace a non-null transaction with zero then do:

```
mask = df.sales == 0 & df.transactions.isna()
df.assign(
    transactions=df.transactions.mask(mask, other=0)

)
```