# Clear column based on a value appearing in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I feel like this should be really simple but I have been stuck on this all day.

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
Name    Date    Graduated    Really?

Bob     2014      Yes   
Bob     2020                   Yes
Sally   1995      Yes
Sally   1999
Sally   1999                   No
Robert  2005                   Yes
Robert  2005      Yes
```

I am grouping by `Name` and `Date`. In each group, if "Yes" appears in `Graduated`, then clear the `Really?` column. And if "Yes" doesn't appear in the group, then leave as is. The output should look like:

```
Name    Date    Graduated    Really?

Bob     2014      Yes   
Bob     2020                   Yes         
Sally   1995      Yes
Sally   1999 
Sally   1999                   No             
Robert  2005                  
Robert  2005      Yes
```

I keep trying different variations of `mask = df.groupby(['Name','Date'])['Graduated'].isin('Yes')` before doing `df.loc[mask, "Really?"] = None`but receive AttributeError (I assume my syntax is incorrect).

Edited expected output.

Comment: Remember that `groupby` does not return a dataframe and so the `isin()` will not work here.

Comment: @le_camerone makes sense, thanks! I am thinking of using a lambda function but the syntax again is eluding me. So far I have tried `df.groupby(['Name','Date']).transform(lambda x: (x == 'Yes').any()` but gives another error.

Comment: This question which was just asked seems to be asking a similar thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71821566/fillna-only-if-the-condition-of-another-column-is-met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = df['Graduated'].eq('Yes').groupby([df['Name'],df['Date']]).transform('any')
df['Really?'] = df['Really?'].mask(s,'')
```

Comment: Change `.where(s)` to `.mask(s, '')` and your answer will be perfect!